# segmentation fault because of sorting function

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

Calling the function `sort_array` gives me the error `segmentation fault (core dumped)` at runtime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE (40)

void sort_array(unsigned char *arr[],int n)
{
    unsigned char tmp;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
         {
             if(arr[j]>arr[i])
             {
                tmp=*arr[i];
                *arr[i]=*arr[j];
                *arr[j]=tmp;
             }
         }
    }
}
int main() {

  unsigned char test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                              114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                              200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                              201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                                7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};
  sort_array(test,SIZE);

  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
      printf("%c ,",test[i]);

}
```

Comment: See: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please note that some of the values you are using to initialize the array aren't printable (ASCII values less than 32). Try `printf("%u ,", (unsigned)test[i]);`.

Comment: A debugger requires you to already know how arrays and pointers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clang` compiler giving following warning message when compiling your code *(the compiler, you are using to compile, must be giving similar warning message)*

```
prg.c:28:14: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'unsigned char [40]' 

to parameter of type 'unsigned char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  sort_array(test,SIZE);
             ^~~~
prg.c:4:32: note: passing argument to parameter 'arr' here
void sort_array(unsigned char *arr[],int n)
                               ^
1 warning generated.
```

One suggestion - Don't ignore the warnings, they are there for some reason.

Warning message indicating that the type of `test` is not compatible with type of `sort_array()` parameter `arr`. The type of `test` is `unsigned char [SIZE]` whereas the type of `arr` is array of `unsigned char` pointers.

You want to sort the array `test` in `sort_array()`. There are two ways you can achieve this:

1. Either pass the pointer to the first element of array `test` to
   `sort_array()`.
2. Pass the `test` array pointer to the `sort_array()`.

The difference in pointer to first element of array and pointer to array is often confusing to the programmers.

Lets discuss **first approach** - pass the pointer to the first element of array `test` to `sort_array()`
When you are doing this

```
sort_array(test,SIZE);
```

that means you are passing the pointer to first element of array to the `sort_array()` because

```
&test[0] -> &(*(test + 0)) -> &(*(test)) -> &(*test) -> test
```

The type of element of `test` array is `unsigned char`, so the type of `arr` parameter of `sort_array()` should be `unsigned char *`. In this case the `sort_array()` prototype should be:

```
void sort_array(unsigned char *arr, int n);
```

In the `sort_array()`, you can access the elements of array like this - `a[i]`, where `i` represent the i<sup>th</sup> element of array `test`. The `sort_array()` :

```
void sort_array(unsigned char *arr, int n) {
    unsigned char tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
         for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
             if(arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Note that in this approach, you need to pass the size of array to be sort. But this also gives flexibility that you can use the `sort_array()` to sort different sizes of array of type `unsigned char []`.

Now the **second approach** - Pass the `test` array pointer to the `sort_array()`

The type of `test` is `unsigned char [SIZE]`, so pointer of its type will be `unsigned char (*) [SIZE]`. That means when you are passing the pointer to `test` array to `sort_array()` like this

```
sort_array(&test);
```

the type of `arr` parameter of `sort_array()` prototype should be:

```
void sort_array(unsigned char (*arr) [SIZE]);
```

Note that, in this case you don't need to pass the array size to `sort_array()` because the pointer knows the size of array it can point to.

When you do

```
sizeof (*arr);
```

You will get

```
40     // because the SIZE is 40
```

In `sort_array()`, you can access the elements of `test` array like this - `(*arr)[i]` where `i` represent the i<sup>th</sup> element of array `test`. When using this approach, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 40

void sort_array(unsigned char (*arr)[SIZE]) {
    unsigned char tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
         for(int j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++) {
             if((*arr)[j] > (*arr)[i]) {
                tmp = (*arr)[i];
                (*arr)[i] = (*arr)[j];
                (*arr)[j] = tmp;
             }
         }
    }
}
int main(void) {

   unsigned char test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                               114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                               200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                               201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                                 7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};

   sort_array(&test);

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      printf("%u", test[i]);
      (i+1) != SIZE ? printf(" ,") : printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
250 ,244 ,230 ,201 ,201 ,200 ,194 ,190 ,177 ,154 ,150 ,123 ,122 ,114 ,100 ,99 ,92 ,90 ,90 ,88 ,87 ,87 ,87 ,76 ,67 ,60 ,45 ,34 ,25 ,23 ,12 ,8 ,8 ,7 ,6 ,6 ,5 ,3 ,2 ,2
```

Note that when printing the sorted array, I am using `%u` format specifier. When you print the ASCII character using `%c`, `printf()` will print the ASCII character corresponding to decimal value `test[i]` but remember that ASCII character from `0` to `31` are non printable characters and your `test` array has values in this range.

The limitation of using pointer to array approach is that the `arr` parameter of `sort_array()` will expect the address of array of type `unsigned char [SIZE]`. If you pass address of an `unsigned char` array of different size other than `SIZE` then compiler will throw warning message.

Of course, the pointer to first element of array approach seems more appropriate in your case but its good to be aware of the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your function data type and you don't need to define it as `unsigned char *arr[]`.

Here is corrected version:

```
void sort_array(unsigned char *arr,int n)
{
    unsigned char tmp;
    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
         for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
         {
             if(arr[j]>arr[i])
             {
                tmp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=tmp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me rubbish values

Comment: @AbdulrhmanAboghanima because you have some unprintable ASCII codes(like 2) in your array.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to sort 1D-array
The variable `unsigned char *arr[]` you declared means that it is a POINTER that points to an ARRAY.

In this case it can also represent an 2D-array.

What you might want is to use `unsigned char *arr` ,which represents a pointer that points to a char.
In this case, you can use `arr[i]` to access it just like the normal array.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above seem to solve your problem.

For printing the sorted char array I would suggest to output the values with %d instead of %c, so you can see the result of the sorting.

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    printf("%d ,", test[i]);
}
```

You will notice, that your function reverse-sorts your array.
If you want your array to be sorted in an ascending order, use the following `sort_array()`:

```
void sort_array(unsigned char *arr,int n)
{
    unsigned char tmp;
    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
         for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
         {
             if(arr[j]<arr[i])
             {
                tmp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=tmp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

The only that has changed here is the `>` sign (to an `<` sign) in the line `if(arr[j]<arr[i])`.